# Which CentOS/RedHat Repo to use for php 5.6+?

Tags: php, centos

All of our webservers are running CentOS 7. We now have some cases where the PHP 5.4.4+, which is the lastest version provided in the [official CentOS & EPEL](https://wiki.centos.org/de/AdditionalResources/Repositories/)  repositories, is not enough anymore. Meaning we have to upgrade PHP **to at least PHP version 5.6**. What is the most **elegant** and **stable** way to do so? 
There are various repositories like [Webtactic](https://webtatic.com) which would offer PHP version 5.6 but in the Official CentOS Repo list Webtactic is listed in the section "Known Problem Repositories". Furthermore compiling php on CentOS is a mess concerning the upgrades...

What would you recommend?

Cheers

Comment: This is probably off-topic as primarily opinion-based, so I won't add an actual answer. But one of my clients has been using [Remi's RPM repository](https://rpms.remirepo.net/) happily for years. The same CentOS list that marks Webtatic as a "known problem repo" lists Remi as "community-approved".

Comment: hey Chris, thank you for sharing your experience!

Comment: I don't really think the question is opinion based, maybe a little experience based, but there are certainly some repositories which are more stable then others, so if someone wants to share his experience, please feel free :-)